# Distinct results from mysql match fulltext search on left join table

Tags: mysql, search, match, left-join

I have this sql query:

```
SELECT `users`.*, `tags`.`usersID`,
(MATCH (`users`.`role`,`users`.`skill`,`users`.`notes`) 
AGAINST ('value' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE WITH QUERY EXPANSION) +
MATCH (`tags`.`tag`)
AGAINST ('value' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE WITH QUERY EXPANSION))
AS score
FROM `users`
LEFT JOIN `tags` on `users`.`id` = `tags`.`usersID` 
WHERE
MATCH (`users`.`role`,`users`.`skill`,`users`.`notes`)
AGAINST ('value' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE WITH QUERY EXPANSION)
OR MATCH (`tags`.`tag`)
AGAINST ('value' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE WITH QUERY EXPANSION)
ORDER BY score DESC
```

the query works amazingly well, but I need to select unique rows, no duplicates.
I am currently solving filtering the backend array, but I'd like to know if there is a way to obtain the array directly from the DB.

```
USERS EXAMPLE

Id: 1
Name: John
Surname: Smith
Role: player
Skill: tester
Notes: can be a writer sometimes

Id: 2
Name: Rudy
Surname: Burr
Role: alchemist
Skill: dj
Notes: he's into skateboarding

...
```

```
TAGS EXAMPLE

Id: 1
usersID: 1
tag: potato juice


Id: 2
usersID: 1
tag: tomato juice


Id: 3
usersID: 1
tag: pepper

Id: 4
usersID: 2
tag: gas

...
```

So if I look for `juice` I'd like to get John just once, not twice.

Comment: You can simply add 
GROUP BY usersID  
before the 
ORDEY BY clause

Comment: I did but it does not work, it seems it has the tag.tag field in the table that cannot be grouped